# What's the formula to calculate the mining profitability for ETC?

Tags: mining, ethereum-classic

I know there are calculators for mining profit, but I need to include the same thing in an app I'm building, what formula do they use for Ethereum Classic?
Also, can I use the same formula for other cryptocurrencies or is it different every time?
Is there some website/guide/etc. that I can use to learn more about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at a [calculator source code](https://github.com/badmofo/ethereum-mining-calculator/blob/90f4e5aae595a6877f1a26b43c15a7db35149a22/index.html#L199), there are some on github and you'll find the exact formula :

> ```
>   $scope.ethPrice = ethereumStats.priceUsd;
>   $scope.netHashGH = (ethereumStats.difficulty / ethereumStats.blockTime) / 1e9;
>   $scope.blockTime = ethereumStats.blockTime;
>   $scope.earnings = {};
>   $scope.computeProfits = function() {
>     var userRatio = $scope.userHash * 1e6 / ($scope.netHashGH * 1e9);
>     var blocksPerMin = 60.0 / $scope.blockTime;
>     var ethPerMin = blocksPerMin * 5.0;
>     $scope.earnings.min = userRatio * ethPerMin;
>     $scope.earnings.hour = $scope.earnings.min * 60;
>     $scope.earnings.day = $scope.earnings.hour * 24;
>     $scope.earnings.week = $scope.earnings.day * 7;
>     $scope.earnings.month = $scope.earnings.day * 30;
>     $scope.earnings.year = $scope.earnings.day * 365;
>   };
> ```

Comment: Thanks, so it's the same for ETH and ETC?

Comment: @Fyde yes, both use the same Ethereum protocol, for the moment...

Comment: care to explain what's the purpose of this line?

    var ethPerMin = blocksPerMin * 5.0;

Comment: answering myself: 1 block = 5 ETH rewards although this might not be the case forever

Comment: @LucaG. Right it should be down to 3eth now after the last Byzantium fork.

Comment: @LucaG. Feel free to fill an issue on the calculator github. Block reward is around 3eth as you can check on https://bitinfocharts.com/ethereum/

Comment: what is the context / significance of '1e5' and '1e9'? (486 and 489). Not sure why those numbers are used?

Comment: @bshea it's 1e6 and 1e9, not 1e5. But I'll assume it's a typo ;) these ratios are used to convert your mining power called hashrate in the same unit. Network hashrate is always defined in Gh/s:giga hash per second and miner rate here is Mh/s: mega hash per second. So to have both in h/s you have to multiply each value by the multiplier of the corresponding unit prefix. giga is 1e9 and mega is 1e6. That's it.

Comment: Ahh thank you - makes sense. I read as hexadecimal and not exponent at first. lol..

Comment: @bshea in JavaScript, hex value is always prefixed by "0x".

Answer (score 8):

Here is rough formula:

```
<probability to mine next block> = <your hash rate> / <total hash rate>
<blocks in month> = <seconds in month> / <avg block time>
<blocks mined per month> = <probability to mine next block> * <blocks in month>
<revenue per month> = <block reward> * <blocks mined per month>
<earnings per month> = <revenue per month> - <expenses>
```

This calculation is only valid if you are mining in a pool.

Also, this is *underestimation* as it does not consider transaction fees and **uncle blocks**.