# Trying to understand how to calculate the profitability of Ethereum mining based on hashrate

Tags: mining, gpu, hashrate

I'm **very** new to Ethereum/cryptocurrencies, I'm trying to understand how to rate the efficiency/profitability of GPU cards

### Question

If I exclude power bills / hardware aquisition costs, am I correct that hashrate is pretty much the only thing that matters to calculate profitability, and that it depends on:

1. GPU Card
2. Hash algorithm

### Story behind

So I [found this post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1575547.msg15890674), where OP is enquiring about hashrate of the GTX 1060.

One of the posts gave these hashrate numbers:

```
Lyra2REv2 ==> 22.5 MH/s
blake2s ==> 1180 MH/s
LBRY ==> 175 MH/s
```

The hashrate difference between algorithm is huge, is this normal?

I found many conflicting hashrate numbers all over the Internet, but most comments I've read are talking about 20 MH/s, which makes the `blake2s 1180 MH/s` rate so extreme that I'm wondering if I'm missing something...

Comment: You are right, you're missing something ;) you can't compare hashrates on different algorithms. All you have to know is hashrate of your card, hashrate of the network and difficulty. However, that's why I just comment and not answering, I can't tell the exact formula. You can look an another post about this calculation :  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11380/405

Comment: @NicolasMassart: thanks, so basically the `GPU card's hashrate` is the same regardless of the algorithm, is that correct?

Comment: No, it's different for each algorithms. If you have 20Mh/s on ETH, it could be 1234Mh/s on another coin. That's why you have to use each coins algorithm formula to calculate profitability.

Comment: the algorithm is always the same for one crypto. Try to find some article about crypto mining, that should help.