# calculate average network hashrate and block time in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, hashrate

If you visit [ethstats](http://ethstats.net/) you see two cards named **AVG NETWORK HASHRATE** and **AVG BLOCK TIME**, How can i get them in geth?

Answer (score 0):

Geth doesn't deliver the blockTime directly.

I've written a simple PHP script that calculates the average blockTime and difficulty: https://github.com/3lue/Average-Blocktime-Difficulty-Calculator

Maybe someone else knows how to get the average hashrate.

**EDIT:** I've found following post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11382

So you should be able to calculate the average network hashrate with this formula (output in GH/s):

> (difficulty / blockTime) / 1e9